# Capitalize dialog popups

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page that opens a dialog, code below

```
function addcustomer() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "customers.php",
        async:true,
        success: function(data){
            $('#pop').html(data).dialog({
                width: 420,
                height: 630,
                modal:true,
                draggable:false,
                resizable:false,
                title:'Customer',
                buttons: {
                    Cancel: function(){
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    Submit: function(){
                        $("#frmcustomer").submit();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

When I open the dialog, I want all inputs and selects capitalized. I tried:

```
select, input { text-transform: capitalize }
```

But it only works after I click anywhere in the dialog. It doesn't capitalize any control when it first opens, I also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("select,input,textarea").uniform();
    $('select, input').capitalize();
});
```

Any idea how to solve?

Comment: Which browser are you using? I can't reproduce it on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/WKMrm/ Are any other scripts interfering? You might need to show the content you load into the popup.

Comment: Try switching to different browsers and see if the problem occurs elsewhere. You can also provide a working sample on http://jsfiddle.net using jQueryUI.

Comment: Okay I forgot this browser issue, it works well on firefox but it causes the same issue on safari and chrome!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WKMrm/ - does this also not work for you in Safari and Chrome?

Comment: No it works fine, I suspect that my code doesnt work because of the uniform I'm using

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much impossible to answer without seeing an example that actually shows the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

**CSS**

```
.capitalize {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

**jquery**

```
success: function(data){
        $('#pop').html(data).dialog({
         .......
         open: function( event, ui ) {
             $(data).find('select, input').addClass('capitalize'); 
             //or ui.find('select, input').addClass('capitalize');
         }
         ........
```

Comment: Trying to capitalize before opening the dialog is a good idea, but still it doesnt work

Comment: still you have `But it only works after I click anywhere in the dialog. ` ??

Comment: Yes, I tried all answers on this page and nothing has changed, it still capitalizes after I click anywhere on the dialog

Comment: have you tried this inside open callback of dialog.. that might do the trick.. let me know if i need to update

Comment: I'm sorry but where exactly do you mean ?

Comment: i mean open callback of dialog... check out the docs http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open... i have updated my code.. check it out...

Comment: thanks for your effort but it didnt work, i dont even find the class capitalize applied  to inputs!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, please edit your answer to $('select, input').css('text-transform','capitalize'); this is the working solution

Comment: @Digitalfortress That's the same solution Rockafella provided to the question which you voted down..?

Comment: @HighwayofLife First It was not me who voted down for Rockfella, also I tried his answer before and it didnt work, it worked only on the open callback of dialog so  the above answer is the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
$('select, input').css('text-transform', 'capitalize');
```

Edit:

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4NVnG/

Answer (score -1):

The fastest/safest way to do this is to use CSS, which is ultimately what jQuery is doing:

```
select, input {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

The problem is that the jQuery function has to fire after the HTML for the selects and inputs becomes visible for jQuery to select. This means that to use jQuery to run capitalize on your selects and inputs in your dialog, you can only do so after the dialog opens. If you use pure CSS, it won't matter when the text appears.

Comment: @Digitalfortress, You might need to provide an example. This many people providing the same answer can't be wrong. I just tested it myself with the jQueryUI dialog and it worked as expected. You can use http://jsfiddle.net with jQueryUI to provide an example.

Comment: All the examples assume that no capitalization occurs, in fact it does only after clicking anywhere on the dialog popup

Comment: @Digitalfortress, This makes no sense. I tested the answers everyone provided using `dialog` and was unable to reproduce the problem you're experiencing. There is something else perhaps happening here that we're not aware of. It could be a browser, toolbar, or something else that's affecting your code. CSS applies instantly to all rendered text, there is no delay. That is the way that browser rendering engines work.